# how to find the free percentage of a drive in c#

Tags: c#

how to find the percentage of the drive in c#

for example

if c: is 100 gb and the used space is 25 gb the free percentage should be 75%

Comment: Free space on a drive you mean?

Comment: There’s no such thing as free space of a directory, only of a drive partition.

Comment: This is called a _drive_ (or partition).

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`DriveInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx), like this:

```
DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo("C");
double percentFree = 100 * (double)drive.TotalFreeSpace / drive.TotalSize;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the free space available on any UNC path (possibly a partition mounted to a directory, or a share), you will have to resort to calling the Windows API.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
        out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable, out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
        out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ulong available;
        ulong total;
        ulong free;

        if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx("C:\\", out available, out total, out free))
        {
            Console.Write("Total: {0}, Free: {1}\r\n", total, free);
            Console.Write("% Free: {0:F2}\r\n", 100d * free / total);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Error getting free diskspace.");
        }

        // Wait for input so the app doesn't finish right away.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You might want to use the available bytes instead of free bytes, depending on your needs:

> lpFreeBytesAvailable:
>   A pointer to a variable that receives the total number of free
>   bytes on a disk that are available to
>   the user who is associated with the
>   calling thread.
>   If per-user quotas are being used, this value may be less than the total
>   number of free bytes on a disk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about free *drive* space, not directories, check out the [DriveInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984629/how-to-find-the-free-percentage-of-a-directory-in-c) class.

You can get info on all the drives:

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

and then iterate over the array until you find the drive you are interested in:

```
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Free space on {0}: {1}", d.Name, d.TotalFreeSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to partitions. IF that is the case, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) should help.

Comment: Partitions do not necessarily have a drive letter though. They can look like ordinary directories using mount points. Shame this method doesn't work for those :(