# Getting Drive Used Space as Percentage

Tags: c#

I have found the following post which gives me the inverse of what I want ([how to find the free percentage of a drive in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984629/how-to-find-the-free-percentage-of-a-drive-in-c-sharp)), but I can't quite wrap my head around how to return the USED space of a drive as a percentage.

Comment: oO 100-what_you_get?

Comment: er... 100 - {free space as percentage} ? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about basic math, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would almost be same as the linked answer like

```
DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo("C");
double percentFree = 100 * (double)(drive.TotalSize - drive.AvailableFreeSpace) / drive.TotalSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo("C");
var totalUsed = drive.TotalSize-drive.TotalFreeSpace;
var percentUsed = 100 * (double)totalUsed / drive.TotalSize;
```